# How to change reference frame value?

Tags: ffmpeg

Hi I am trying to change reference frames from 4 to 3 but it didn't work.

Have tried to change gop, b frames with reference frames but didn't work

```
ffmpeg8 -report -ss 00:00:00.000 -t 00:04:47.000 -i /input1 -ss 00:04:47.001 -t 00:04:00.000 -i /input2 -filter_complex "[0:v:0]crop=out_h=576:y=32,yadif=1:-1:0[part1crop]; [1:v:0]crop=out_h=576:y=32,yadif=1:-1:0[part2crop]; [0:a:0]pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c1[part1audioStereo]; [1:a:0]pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c1[part2audioStereo]; [part1crop][part1audioStereo][part2crop][part2audioStereo]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vconcat][aconcat]" -map '[vconcat]' -codec:v libx264 -profile:v high -level 4.1 -coder 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -bf 3 -b:v 1500k -video_track_timescale 25 -r 25 -s:v 1024x768 -aspect 4:3 -x264opts keyint=50:ref=4:bframes=3:subq=6:trellis=2:8x8dct=1:b-pyramid=0:vbv-bufsize=1500:nal-hrd=cbr -map '[aconcat]' -codec:a libfdk_aac -ar 48000 -ac 2 -b:a 128K -write_tmcd off output.mp4
```

result:

Video
ID                                       : 226 (0xE2)
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.1
Format settings                          : 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, RefFrames               : 4 frames
Duration                                 : 35 s 80 ms
Nominal bit rate                         : 15.0 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 024 pixels
Height                                   : 576 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Writing library                          : x264 core 148

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works here by changing to `ref=3` within `-x264opts`.

Comment: Your comments helped much. But there is another problem output file is not having audio it is silent. input format is PCM with 8 Channels I am trying to convert to AAC with 2 channels. Code is as above mentioned.

Comment: Remove the pan and directly feed the audio to concat.

Comment: Managed to get it.